# ¿Cómo validar ciertos Inputs con el Validator de Bootstrap 5?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

¿Cómo validar solo ciertos campos de un formulario con el validador de Bootstrap 5?

Mi validador ya funciona, el problema es que aplica a todo el formulario y solo quiero que se aplique a ciertos inputs:

[image]

Este es mi Código:

```
'use strict'
    var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')


 Array.prototype.slice.call(forms)
     .forEach(function (form) {
         form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
             if (!form.checkValidity()) {
                 event.preventDefault()
                 event.stopPropagation()
             }

             form.classList.add('was-validated')
             
         }, false)
     })
```

Código Html, en `class` es donde hago la referencia para todo el formulario:

```
 <form id="frmEquipo" class="RegisterForm needs-validation" name="frmEquipo" role="form" action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate">
```

Clase de input :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: inserta el código HTML del formulario también.

Comment: ya actualice la pregunta

Comment: directamente pones una `class` en el `form` es obvio que te va agarrar todos los campos como obligatorios, te recomiendo que lo insertes campo por campo el requerimiento.

Comment: Lo quite del `Form`  y lo puse en el `Class` de los inputs  pero solo recarga la pagina

Comment: Agrega el código completo del formulario, qué clases estás definiendo en cada uno de los inputs?

Comment: ya actualice la pregunta

Comment: Por eso, ahí dice que el input con id Modelo se está validando por la clase needs-validation, si quieres que ese campo no lo tome en cuenta, elimina la clase.